# Suspend failed once and forever?

Tags: suspend, acpi, lid

I accidentally closed the lid and the system went to suspend (Ubuntu 14.04) but it seemed to last forever. So I forced quit the suspend. After I restarted Ubuntu and tried to let it suspend, it failed to do so complaining about a system error.

I searched online and found "acpi" issues and known bugs for Ubuntu but don't know whether this is related to my problem.

Comment: We need to know the exact system error message please :)

Comment: sorry, I cannot provide this information. I don't know how to copy the error message out, it is automatically sent to the company for analysis

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but when I issued:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

and then as APT suggested, ran:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

after a system restart, the issue was resolved.

Maybe somebody can explain to me why.

Comment: It could be this issue is due to an update on ubuntu. After I updated the system as suggested, the issue came back. I don't know whether this is indeed the reason. If so, how could I rewind my system back to the previous good setting?