# Why is my system not waking up from suspend?

Tags: suspend, power-management, 15.04, resume

I freshly installed Ubuntu 15.04 sharing a preexisting home partition (Mint 17.1).
However, in neither Mint or Ubuntu the computer is waking up from suspend mode. The status LED keeps blinking and the screen stays off, no matter how much keyboard or mouse input i give to wake it up. The hardware is a lenovo ThinkPad E540. What can I do to further narrow down the problem or even resolve it?

```
lspci -vnn | grep -A12 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:502a]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a problem introduced by lenovo and solved with a BIOS update of the affected laptop E540.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1340376

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-E-and-Edge/E540-Suspend-Resume-failure/td-p/1868488

http://support.lenovo.com/jp/de/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-edge-e440/downloads/DS037208

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sounds goofy, but I believe I have encountered the same issue. What I have always done to resolve this is pressing either the "home" key or the "delete" key it will take you to the screen where you can enter your password, then it manages to login and you're good from there.

Comment: I've tried all keys for waking up the computer, it just stays in suspend.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, also hibernate used to work fine on 14.10 and it sometimes doesn't load now that I use 15.04. I have removed unity-lens-shopping as I hope it will help, but we shall see. First finishing up some work and then trying if suspend won freeze after wake up now. At first I thought it was because I was keeping my Ruby Rails server running, but suspending after stopping the server didn't fix the issue.

I am looking for a long term fix and I was hoping Ubuntu devs will come up with it, looking around it seems only Lenovo laptops have this issue, I own a Y50, if more info is needed regarding this issue I am happy to oblige.

As a temporary fix you can enable hibernation and use it to load up your system after working, but it can be a bit unstable. Here's the URL for [enabling hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation).

PS. Removing unity-lens-shopping did fix the freeze on waking from suspend :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried restarting computer? There is another question about a similar issue, where the commands used to resolve the issue are:
    sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
then
    sudo apt-get autoremove

https://askubuntu.com/a/620864/407406

Comment: this is a long time issue i have and i restart my computer regulary, namely every single time i move it. Because it is the only workaround if suspend does not work. Also there is no unity-lens-shopping in Mint, and because the same problem exists on Mint it can't be the right answer.